# CSS fit image to element height and maintain ratio on resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created an element with an image to the left and text to the right.

[image]

On screen resize I want to maintain the image ratio while having it extend vertically in the element. Instead the image reduces in size like so:

[image]

How can I always keep the image extended in height but maintain its aspect ratio?

I am using flex in my code

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYmjMK

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 860px;
}

.item {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 65%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.image a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On screen resize I want to maintain the image ratio while having it extend vertically in the element. Instead the image reduces in size like so:

Most images can't fit in the container top-bottom and left-right while maintaining aspect ratio across all screen sizes. One thing you could do on smaller screen sizes is to have the image take 100% of the screen's width and overlay the text or position it below. Even then, on smaller screen sizes, the image won't take 100% of the height and maintain aspect ratio. Also if you have too much text, it will bleed off the image.

Here's an example with text overlaid. :

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 860px;
}

.item {
   display: flex;
   background-color: #ddd;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 65%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.image a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .image {
    width: 100vw;    
  }

  .text {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(192,192,192), rgb(0,0,0)); /*Fallback*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.6));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441986380878-c4248f5b8b5b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
          Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

If you want to maintain aspect ratio and basically zoom in on a portion of the image:

```
.image img {
  height: 100%
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 860px;
}

.item {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 65%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.image a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441986380878-c4248f5b8b5b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
      Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.Sed hendrerit. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Integer tincidunt. Nullam vel sem. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio.
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your img tag:

```
width: auto;
height: 100%;
```

And put this on your div.image:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Then you might want to play around with the positioning so that the image is centered instead of left / top aligned.

Answer (score 0):

CSS fit image to element height and maintain ratio on resize, you css height img:

```
.image img {height: 100%;}
```

[image]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBNPzm

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer. stevecomrie below also included it in his answer